# Apache 2.4.23: gzip for HTTP 503

Tags: apache-2.4, http, gzip, mod-deflate

Can Apache be instructed to gzip the contents of an HTTP 503 response?

A page of a website that I manage needs to be temporarily removed. Not only
does HTTP 503 aptly describe the situation but it also preserves search
engine ranking. The response's body contains HTML markup so that the page is
branded like the rest of the website. Since gzip is not triggered, I am
seeing a significant increase in transfer times for this page.

All other pages are gzipped just fine.

Thanks in advance!